# WCF service that use encryption for some clients only

Tags: wcf, security, encryption

I am designing a WCF service. Is is possible to define a service that can handle encrypted messages from some of the clients (on untrusted channel), but also not encrypted messages (for the clients that are on trusted channel) ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it should be generally possible. There can be some other requirements which would break this possibility but with simple configuration you can use single service with two endpoints - one exposing unencrypted communication and one exposing encrypted communication. You just have to make sure that each client set can access only selected endpoint - that is usually not related to WCF but to computer or network configuration.